# Copying the contents of file to another

Tags: autoit

I am new to Auto It and I want to copy the contents of a file(any type) to another by creating a word document on the hard drive using Auto It script.

Could anyone help me please?

Note: I want to open a file, read the contents and write them to another file by creating it in any specified location as per my wish.

Please help me in this aspect

Thanks in adv

Comment: What is the reason for using a Word document? I can't see how that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;$sourceFile="c:\source.file"
;$destFile="c:\dest.file"

; Open source file, file must exist
$sourceFile=FileOpenDialog("Source file", "c:\", "All(*.*)", 1)
If @error Then
    MsgBox("No file choosen")
    Exit
EndIf

; Open dest file
$destFile=FileOpenDialog("Destination file", "c:\", "All(*.*)")
If @error Then
    MsgBox("No file choosen")
    Exit
EndIf

$result=FileCopy($sourceFile, $destFile)
If ($result = 0) Then
    MsgBox("copy failed")
EndIf
```

Answer (score 1):

A file does not contain what you see on the screen if you open it. It does, but it's not a 1:1 copy.

Open any .docx or .zip file with a text editor (like notepad). You won't see your written text or files/folders in there, only things like "ÐÏà¡±á". Unreadable to humans. The data in the file is different from what a program like Word or WinZip shows you is in a file. There are a couple of reasons for this.

A file needs to be easy for computers to read and edit (not humans). It is formatted in a certain way that makes it easy for a programmer to parse. (Parsing is how a computer reads a file -- but this is oversimplified.) The file as you see it after opening in a program is easy for humans to read and edit.

So reading from any file in the sense of this is not going to work:

- Read out the file
- Put the contents in clipboard (Ctrl+C idea)
- Paste in Word (Ctrl+V idea)

because you're going to end up with a bunch of unreadable (to humans) nonsense. So then the question: How DO you do it?

You pick a number of formats you want to read out from: docx, doc, xls, pdf. Not simply "anything ever invented and ever will be". You find a converter for each of the formats, or even write one if you think you can do that, and a writer for your output format (docx).

In terms of a "simple project that can convert anything to docx"... You're screwed. It's complicated!

Comment: Of course the advantage of AutoIt is that there is a way to automate anything with a COM interface, including word. That makes a converter fairly simple.